# CSS transform animation causes visual glitch in subsequent blurred elements (Chrome only)

Tags: css, google-chrome

So this is a bit strange. I have a blurred element (`filter: blur(..)`, just a black box for example here) that is scaled up slightly (`transform: scale(2)`) in order to hide the blurred edges. Now when a *preceding* element animates the `transform` property, the blurred element shows a visual glitch (perhaps losing its `scale(2)`, but I'm not sure) for the duration of the animation.

I see this behavior in Chrome (on Linux), but not Firefox.

I have tried adding `backface-visibility: hidden` and `translateZ(0)` to the blurred element, but these actually cause the same visual glitch just described. I am not sure why this is.

Any workarounds or insight into this issue is appreciated! Here is a minimal reproduction:

https://jsfiddle.net/malwilley/tz4fwmu2/

```css
button {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  transition: transform 500ms;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.blurred {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<button>Hover me</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="blurred" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `transform: translateY(20px)` instead of `margin-top: 20px` the bug will be fixed.

```css
button {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  transition: transform 500ms;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

.container {
  transform: translateY(20px);
  overflow: hidden; /* remove overflow: hidden to see blur */
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.blurred {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<button>Hover me</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="blurred" />
</div>
```

Comment: These seems like a hack, but a hack that works! In fact, this could be simplified to just putting `transform: scale(1)` on `.container` and keeping the rest the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes these glitches in Chrome appear, when you have software rendering without support by the 3D graphics processor.

As far as I understand, you can trigger 3d support by using any Z coordinate `transform`.
Thus appending `translateZ(0)` to your scaling transform in `.blurred` makes the glitch go away.

### Old solution

```css
button {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  transition: transform 500ms;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}
++ 
.blurred {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.2) translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<button>Hover me</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="blurred" />
</div>
```

### New solution

I changed my style a little bit
It's now

```
.container {
    /* ... */
    transform: scale(1);
}
.blurred {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

I took another trigger for 3D rendering and used it on the `.container` instead of the `.blurred` element

```css
button {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  transition: transform 500ms;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.blurred {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<button>Hover me</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="blurred" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This may be an issue with Chrome on Linux specifically (I've added that info to the description), or perhaps I didn't my intention well enough.

With this change, I see a blurred outline on the box with and without hover: https://i.imgur.com/eebIFmw.png

My intended behavior was to have a clear outline which is not affected by hovering the button element. It's a bit confusing since I chose a black box where the blur is not actually visible...